# Setting default Linux Shell in RHEL7 using Active Directory

Tags: bash, shell, tcsh, active-directory

I have a client who has an install script that needs to run under `/bin/tcsh` as the shell on their Active Directory Domain Joined RHEL7 Virtual Machine. 
This install script will be run using a service account called, `serviceaccount`. Now, this account is granted rights because of a group it's a member of `Admins`.

The end user logs into the VM, `sudo su serviceaccount` and then runs the shell.

We have modified `serviceaccount`'s attribute `loginShell` to be set to `/bin/tcsh`.

Now, the Unix admin team set `serviceaccount`'s profile to be `/bin/tcsh` and it can be verified using the user's environmental settings. Somehow, the install script is finding `/bin/bash`, and it seems totally random, but it pulls incorrectly more than 95% of the time.

I don't see any shell attributes in AD Groups, nor anything else close in the user attributes, besides the `loginShell`.

I've also verified it's set correctly in every Domain Controller in the environment.

```
getent passwd serviceaccount
serviceaccount:*:123456789:123456789:serviceaccount:/home/serviceaccount:/bin/bash
```

(As another test, we stood up a new VM that this account has never been logged into and `getent` still shows `/bin/bash`.)

Any ideas?

Comment: Charles ge the shebang in the script to #@/bin/tech rather than setting the users shell

Comment: how exactly is the the installer being launched?

Comment: The application the script is attempting to install also requires the user account to be set to /bin/tcsh, so changing the script only puts a wet band-aid on it. Thank you though.

Comment: The installer is being launched by ssh'ing into the box using a normal account, then sudo su serviceaccount. Then, /home/serviceaccount/folder/installerscript.sh

Comment: @roaima your comment doesn't help the discussion. The end user is an admin on the box, but the installer needs to be run as a serviceaccount for security reasons. Also, just because someone has sudo access doesn't mean they have root access.

Comment: The `/home/serviceaccount/folder/installerscript.sh` script should use a `#!`-line pointing to the correct interpreter.  This does _not_ need to be the user's login shell.

Comment: JoshB regardless of whether or not the end user is an admin on the box, why not just `sudo -u serviceaccount -s`. This does not require root privileges because there is no need for `su`. Your suggested command _does_ require root privileges to run.

Comment: Back to your original question. Are you using native LDAP, or SSSD, Winbind, or something else to map the AD credentials into the Linux-based environment?

Comment: We're using SSSD to map AD creds

Answer (score 0):

pretty sure you'd be using AD auth via sssd set by authconfig. In the /etc/sssd/sssd.conf, there will be a default shell set for the AD domain/realm. That's where /bin/bash is coming from.
As for setting the shell on a per account basis? not sure how to override that sssd default.